# How to make a button move by touching an arrow key on the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I was wondering how to make a button move like up, down, right, or left, by touching an arrow key on my keyboard. I have tried:

```
button1.Location.X += 1;
```

But, I get an error saying how it's not a variable. So, I also tried:

```
public int xPos, yPos;
```

Then, down a bit under form1_keydown:

```
xPos = Convert.ToInt32(button1.Location.X);
yPos = Convert.ToInt32(button1.Location.Y);
if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
{
    xPos += 1;
}
```

But, it just doesn't work. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `button1.Location = new Point(button1.Left + 1, button1.Top);`?

Answer (score 2):

I oversimplify a little bit to make it clear (and I skip all checks you have to do) but it may be something like this:

```
switch (e.KeyData)
{
    case Keys.Right:
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Left + 1, button1.Top);
        break;
    case Keys.Left:
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Left - 1, button1.Top);
        break;
    case Keys.Up:
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Left, button1.Top - 1);
        break;
    case Keys.Down:
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Left, button1.Top + 1);
        break;
}
```

Comment: It doesnt move when i press down a key :(

Comment: Well, it depends **where** you put this code. Moreover don't forget that form won't get notification of pressed keys when a focusable control is selected (unless key preview is enabled).

Comment: Ok. Where exactly would i put keypreview being enabled? :D @Adriano

Comment: It's property [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) (see link for details). You may even use it to move the control with focus (but this will interfer with "normal" events because in arrows, tab, ESC and few other keys are _special_). See also [IsInputKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details (and a complete example of that). In case you have any problem to handle keyboard events do not refrain to post **another question** about that.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X + 1, button1.Location.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new location for your button, you cannot modify only X or Y because `Point` (The `Location` property type) is a `struct`.

You can do this, for example, on the `KeyUp` event of your form (Don't forget to actually wire the event, and not just copy/paste):

```
private void OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X + 1, button1.Location.Y);
    }
}
```

**Important note :** If you go that way, do not forget to set `KeyPreview = true;` on your form, or the Key events will never fire.